# Check if we're the second or last sunday of the month today

Tags: datetime

How can I check if today is the second or last sunday of this month?
My effort:

```
{% set now = now|date('U') %}
{% set monthyear = now|date('F Y') %}
{% set secondSunday = now|date_modify("#{monthyear} second sunday")|date('U') %}
{% set lastSunday = now|date_modify("#{monthyear} last sunday")|date('U') %}

{# check if now is second or last sunday #}                    
{% if now == secondSunday or now == lastSunday %}
   {# YES, today is the second or the last sunday #}
{% else %}
   {# NOPE #}
{% endif %
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
DateTime::modify(): Failed to parse time string (juni 2017 second sunday) at position 0 (j): The timezone could not be found in the database
```

**Maybe it doesn't work because the monthyear variable is formed in dutch and not english? (juni = june) If this is the case, how can I modify this to english in order to get it to work?**

Also, my timezone is correctly set to UTC+2 (CEST) - Europe/Brussels via Settings > General

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Maybe it doesn't work because the monthyear variable is formed in dutch and not english?

Yes that's part of the problem. Have a look at PHP's [relative formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) page to see what it supports.

You can actually pull off what you're doing with the `this` keyword.

```
{% set secondSunday = now|date_modify("second sunday of this month")%}
{% set lastSunday = now|date_modify("last sunday of this month") %}
```

You also don't need to define (or override) [`now`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/global-variables#now) since Craft will always set that to a DateTime object for you.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!